# Ошибка с применением метода

Tags: python, классы

Добрый день изучаю классы на Python, создаю легендарного сапера)
Ошибка с передачей аргумента

```
from classes import *
import random

bomb_ratio = 3 


#Создание класса и индексов для класса
set_cell = [ 'x' + str(i) for i in range(9)]
for i in range(len(set_cell)):
    exec('{i} =  Cell({index})'.format(i=set_cell[i], index=i))

#Создание заряженных ячеек
x0.now_dangerous()
```

TypeError: now_dangerous() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Сам класс

```
class Cell(object):

    def __init__(self, index):
        self.index = index
        self.charge = 0
 
    def now_dangerous():
        #self.charge = 0
        pass
```

В чем ошибка?

Comment: `exec('{i} =  Cell({index})'.format(i=set_cell[i], index=i))` - очень плохая практика. Надо заводить массив объектов, а не создавать их динамически.

Comment: @Михаил Муругов set_cell = [ 'x' + str(i) for i in range(9)] Данные с именами содержаться здесь, в зависимости от количество строк и столбцов будут меняться

Comment: В этом ничего хорошего нет. Даже более того - это очень плохой код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Любому методу класса в Python при вызове первым аргументом автоматически передаётся `self` – объект этого класса, для которого вызывается метод (это делается для того, чтобы метод "понимал", с каким именно объектом он работает, объектов класса ведь может быть много, а метод на всех один). Причём передаётся всегда, даже если он Вам там не нужен. Следовательно, чтобы всё работало, этот аргумент нужно принимать. Перепишите метод `now_dangerous` так:

```python
def now_dangerous(self):
    #self.charge = 0
    pass
```

Comment: Спасибо)  Лучше использовать методы для изменение атрибутов или менять их присвоением?

Comment: @Agros, лучше использовать `property`

Comment: @Agros, если мой ответ решил проблему, примите его зелёной галкой. А насчёт изменения атрибутов, это тема для отдельного обсуждения. Как программист С++ скажу: лучше используйте методы. На Python в эти тонкости не вникал. Попробуйте задать отдельный вопрос на эту тему, хотя он претендует быть закрытым как слишком абстрактный, но всё же, здесь я не считаю себя достаточно компетентным.

Comment: @Agros, вот, Вам уже подсказал более знающий человек :)